# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED After Localisation to Arabic

Tags: java, android, xml, localizable.strings

I have an app which is due for localisation, two languages are english and arabic(ar), I have created respective folders for my raw files and values

1. raw-ar
2. values-ar

After adding values folder and adding respective translated strings.xml file it gives above error. I have excluded string like app_name and so on from translation.

If I remove the localisation support mainly values folder it works , not able to understand whats going wrong.

> ```
> <resources>
> <string name="english">English</string>
> <string name="arabic">العربية</string>
> <string name="title">المشرف العام للمياه في فرع المنطقة الشرقية القطيف منطقة</string>
> <string name="title_activity_menu">MenuActivity</string>
>
> <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
> <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
>
> <string name="action_settings">إعدادات</string>
> <string name="home">الصفحة الرئيسية</string>
> <string name="settings">إعدادات</string>
> <string name="add_ticket">إضافة تذكرة</string>
> <string name="search_ticket">البحث تذكرة</string>
> <string name="about">حول</string>
>
> <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
> <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
> <string name="ticket_info">معلومات تذكرة</string>
> <string name="report_type">نوع التقرير **</string>
> <string name="chosse_from">- اختار -</string>
> <string name="area">منطقة</string>
> <string name="district">منطقة</string>
> <string name="description">وصف</string>
> <string name="reporter_info">معلومات مراسل</string>
> <string name="enter_desc">إدخال وصف</string>
> <string name="reporter_name">اسم المراسل</string>
> <string name="enter_name">أدخل الاسم</string>
> <string name="mobile_no">رقم المحمول. *</string>
> <string name="enter_mobile">إدخال رقم الجوال</string>
> <string name="id_number">هوية شخصية. عدد *</string>
> <string name="enter_id">إدخال رقم الهوية</string>
> <string name="send">إرسال</string>
> <string name="reset">إعادة تعيين</string>
> <string name="requester_info">معلومات الطالب</string>
> <string name="search">بحث تذاكر</string>
> <string name="request_info">طلب معلومات</string>
> <string name="request_no">طلب لا</string>
> <string name="request">يدخل طلب لا.</string>
> <string name="search1">بحث</string>
> <string name="firstLineAbout">المديرية العامة للمياه بالمنطقة الشرقية في الاختصاصات التالية:</string>
> <string name="secondLineAbout">- هل كل أنواع النشاط الذي يستهدف منشأة خدمات المياه والصرف الصحي.</string>
> <string name="fourthLineAbout">- تصميم وتنفيذ إدارة وتشغيل الشرف والصرف الصحي وخطة المياه.</string>
> <string name="sixthLineAbout">رؤية</string>
>
> <string name="select_area">الرجاء تحديد المنطقة الأولى.</string>
> <string name="camer_perm_err">ونفى أذونات الكاميرا عند بدء التشغيل، يرجى اصلاحها من إعدادات الهاتف.</string>
> <string name="please_wait">أرجو الإنتظار...</string>
> <string name="upload_err">حدث خطأ أثناء تحميل الصورة.</string>
> <string name="save_err">لقد حدث خطأ أثناء حفظ البيانات.</string>
> <string name="doesnt_exists">سجل مع طلب رقم] لا يوجد.</string>
> <string name="field_err">يرجى تعبئة جميع الحقول الضرورية (النوع، المنطقة، منطقة، الوصف، مراسل معلومات).</string>
> <string name="all_err">يرجى ملء جميع المعلومات اللازمة.</string>
>
> <string name="lang_title1">مشرف العامة للمياه بالمنطقة الشرقية</string>
> <string name="lang_title2">فرع منطقة القطيف</string>
>
> <string-array name="areas">
>     <item>Qatif</item>
>     <item>Tarout</item>
>     <item>Saihat</item>
>     <item>Safwa</item>
> </string-array>
>
> <string name="download_queue_provider_authority">com.amazonaws.mobile.downloader-com.mwa.vcmwa</string>
> <!-- This can be anything, but it should be unique to the app. -->
> <string name="content_file_provider_authority">com.mwa.vcmwa.fileprovider</string>
> <string name="back_search">عودة إلى البحث</string>
> <string name="fiftLineAbout">- الوفاء نظام التكلفة المخطط لها</string>
> <string name="gps">نظام تحديد المواقع (الموقع)</string>
> <string name="seventhLineAbout">ونحن نتطلع إلى تقديم خدمات المياه والصرف         الصحي لجميع محافظات ومدن وقرى وهجر المنطقة الشرقية وفقا لأحدث
> التقنيات ورفع مستوى وجودة الخدمة كما هو مطلوب من قبل المواطنين
> والمقيمين</string>
> <string name="thirdLineAbout">- إعداد وتنفيذ وتطوير محطات المياه ومعالجة          مياه الصرف الصحي ومشاريع المياه الشبكات.</string>
> <string name="app_name" translatable="false">QWR</string>
> <string name="add_images">اضف صور (حد أقصى 2)</string>
>
> </resources>
> ```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true">

    <service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />

    <service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobile.downloader.service.DownloadService" />

    <activity android:name="com.mwa.vcmwa.activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.mwa.vcmwa.activities.LanguageActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.mwa.vcmwa.activities.MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name="com.mwa.vcmwa.activities.NewTicket"></activity>


    <receiver android:name="com.amazonaws.mobile.downloader.service.NetworkStateListener"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobile.downloader.query.DownloadQueueProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/download_queue_provider_authority"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
    </provider>

</application>
```

Comment: but you also have the default folders in your project?

Comment: yes I do have values and raw folders

Comment: and all values that are in the arabic folders are also in the default folders? They HAVE TO BE in both folders. Let´s say, you have a text file in raw folder written for the arabic, then it also has to be in the default one.

Comment: Same with the strings.xml, every value inside the strings.xml of ar folder have to be in the default strings.xml

Comment: yes every values is present there just few are marked as non translatable

Comment: is there any reference in your mainfest to strings.xml

Comment: maybe you can show us your manifest...

Comment: ok adding manifest file

Comment: Yes there is a reference to strings.xml in there but i have set those string to non translatable in localised string file

Comment: both strings `string/title_activity_menu` and `string/download_queue_provider_authority` are in both files? Sorry for the repeating questions, but after developing for years, I know little details can be overseen. And `string/app_name`too?

Comment: these are declared as non translatable in strings.xml so they don't appear in both

Comment: manifest tag just not pasted?

Comment: Yes missed that , but its there

Comment: just tried with some other localisation other than arabic and file wasn't translated still it gave error, so its more likely related to something else than language

Comment: ok, what you said in your comment **few are marked as non translatable**...in both strings.xml with the same value?

Comment: Marked non translatable means they are excluded from translated file

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/41109617/939501

Comment: I am asking because in your above strings.xml, there are strings like that: `<string name="app_name" translatable="false">QWR</string>` with the `translatable` tag. Here, it has to be in both strings, maybe you missed it?

Comment: That tag is set to false so they won't appear in translated file actually

Answer (score 1):

Strange enough or may be not, if you are referencing a package name from strings.xml into manifest file then don't , for me it was giving the above mentioned error, as soon as i put hard coded strings instead of from string resource, it all started working fine.